# Module not found error when integrating a chatbot into a website

Tags: javascript, python, file, path, chatbot

I am trying to integrate a chatbot into my website. Previously, the chatbot code was in a separate folder, but I have now merged it within my website codebase to have everything in one place. When I try to add the chatbot to my website by including  in my code, I encounter the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 16:0-92
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/layout/chatbot-solicitors-website/chatbot-deployment/app' in '/Users/parisvinuya/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/Solicitor's Website/solicitors-website/src'
```

Here is the code snippet from my app.js file:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import appcss from "./App.module.css";

import AboutUs from "./pages/AboutUs";
import BookOnline from "./pages/BookOnline";
import Firm from "./pages/Firm";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import LogIn from "./pages/LogIn";
import Publications from "./pages/Publications";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer";
import ContactUs from "./components/layout/ContactUs";
import ChatWithUsButton from "./components/layout/ChatWithUsButton";
import ChatBot from "./components/layout/chatbot-solicitors-website/chatbot-deployment/app";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={appcss.pagecontainer}>
      <div className={appcss.contentwrap}>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about-us" element={<AboutUs />} />
          <Route path="/book-online" element={<BookOnline />} />
          <Route path="/firm" element={<Firm />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn />} />
          <Route path="/publications" element={<Publications />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <ChatBot />
      <ChatWithUsButton />
      <ContactUs />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my app.py file containing the Flask backend code under the file pathway './components/layout/chatbot-solicitors-website/chatbot-deployment/app':

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

from chat import get_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def index_get():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.post("/predict")                   
def predict():
   text = request.get_json().get("message")
   # TO-DO: check if text is valid
   response = get_response(text)
   message = {"answer": response}
   return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

The chatbot code is located at "./components/layout/chatbot-solicitors-website/chatbot-deployment/app". However, when I try to include the ChatBot component, I receive the "Module not found" error.

I have verified that the file path is correct, and I have already merged the chatbot code within my website's codebase. Can anyone help me understand why I am encountering this error and how I can resolve it?

Comment: oh, can javascript import python now?

Comment: well I am following a youtube tutorial and it seemed to have worked

Comment: Oh, it worked? so what's the `Module not found` **error** you asked about

Comment: I recently discovered that JavaScript actualy cannot directly import Python modules HAHA, which resulted in an issue I'm facing with my Flask backend and React frontend integration. Initially, I attempted to import the Python file (app.py) into my JavaScript code, but nothing was displayed. The challenge I'm encountering is that the app.js file relies on running app.py first, as I call app.js from app.py. So I'm not sure what to do now..

Comment: Is the tutorial you are following trying to achieve *exactly* what you are? i.e. adding this python chatbot within a website?

Comment: no it is not.. the tutorial was just for the chatbot only